# C++ While statement not working with string and "or"

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

I'm new to C++, teaching myself via youtube and some books I bought. I can not for the life of me figure out why the 2nd while statement will not work. from a mathematical stand point I feel it should work. If month does not = june or july then do the if else statement. But even when I run the right answer it always runs the if not the else. I feel it has something to do with it being a string, so I tested it without the or "||" and it worked. So maybe it has to do with combining strings and or statements. So did research on using these together and could not find much. Thanks for the help.

```
int main()
{
    int year;
    int day = 0;
    string month = "x";

    do
    {
        if (day == 0)
        {
            cout << "hello" << endl;
            cout << "Please Enter your B-Day as Day, Month, Year" << endl;
            cout << "day" << endl;
            cin >> day;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a correct day" << endl;
            cin >> day;
        }

    } while (day > 31 || day < 1);

    do
    {
        if (month == "x")
        {
            cout << "Please enter the month you were born" << endl;
            cin >> month;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please Enter a correct Month." << endl;
            cin >> month;
        }
    }
    **while (month != "june" || month != "july");**


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
while (month != "june" && month != "july");
```

Or alternatively,

```
while (!(month == "june" || month == "july"));
```

Rather than:

```
while (month != "june" || month != "july");
```

Your program will be working fine even with multiple logical OR.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just going to open my desecrate mathematics book to see what I was forgetting.

Comment: Or just change `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (month != "june" || month != "july");
```

There is something called short-circuit evaluation in C++ which will in this case will not evaluate the right of `||` if the first operand returns true. Likewise for `&&`, it will not evaluate right operand if first is false. So be sure how you want the logic to behave and write the code.

Comment: True, but this would be wrong with or without short-circuit evaluation. `a != 1 || a != 2` evaluates to true if `a` is either not equal to 1 or not equal to 2 - and since `a` cannot be both 1 and 2 at the same time, it is always not equal to at least one of them.

Comment: yes! that is indeed the idea of short-circuit evaluation. TRUE || ANYTHING, always evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: Yes, but the first term can evaluate to false (the month can be june). The problem OP was facing is that it is an or statement where it is impossible for both terms to be false at the same time: You can only ever have `true || true`, `true || false`, or `false || true` - it is never `false || false` so the full statement never evaluates to false.